# Message Passing from Content Scripts to Background Page in Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

### Google Chrome Extensions Message Passing Problem :

In this Chrome Extension

**My Popup Page:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getMessage);
getMessage();

function getMessage()
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });//getting response from content script
    });
}
```

**My Script Page :**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); 
  });
```

I am not getting any response from the content script.

Edits:

As per @**serg** , i have moved the code to the background page. But still, it is not working

Comment: yes, this is the id of the currently selected tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener if you have popup page attached to the browser action button, it won't fire.

- Remove popup, leave only button
- Move everything into background page.
- Replace `tab.id` with `null`.
- Remove `createFile();` call at the beginning as it won't do anything in this case (content script isn't ready to listen yet).
- Don't use alerts for debugging extension, use `console.log()`.

Comment: i have edited the code to the actual one, which was working fine for me, pls chk